# What's causing "The patch target could not be located" error when running smart updater commands for oracle middleware?

Tags: oracle, installation, weblogic, middleware, patch

I'm trying to automate patch updates for weblogic using powershell. From what I read the easiest way to do this is by using oracle's smart updater utility. However, when I run the following command (see below) it gives me "The patch target could not be located. The installation specified may not be of a supported version."

```
.\bsu.cmd -install -patch_download_dir=c:\source -patchlist=EJUW -prod_dir=c:\oracle\Middleware\wlserver -verbose
```

I couldn't find many references that discuss this particular error, but from what I did find it looked like it might be an issue of how the smart updater patch was installed. However, I'm not familiar enough with Oracle's technologies to know exactly what's wrong with my domain structure. I've attached screenshots showing what my middleware directory looks like, as well as the registry and  product.properties files (the latter of which is located in my wlserver folder). Thank you for any advice.

[image: Middleware folders]

[image: Registry file]

[image: Product.properties file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSU was used with 11g. From 12c you have to use OPatch to patch your Oracle's products.